# Can't increment an empty set with mysql

Tags: mysql, coalesce, is-empty, ifnull

I'm trying to write an update that will increment the value of auth_id; however, if there is no value, I'd like to set it to 1.  I can't even get the select to give me a 0 value to increment.

```
mysql> describe sequences;
+---------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type                     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| auth_id | int(5) unsigned zerofill | NO   |     | 00000   |       |
+---------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I thought this would work.

```
mysql> select ifnull(auth_id,0) from sequences;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Or this...

```
mysql> select coalesce(auth_id, 0) from sequences;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to insert an initial value

Comment: ifnull() can't create a record from nothing. if there's no records in the tables, there's nothing for ifnull to compare/work on .

Comment: How many rows do you expect this table to have in total (ever)?

Comment: `... WHERE auth_id = ''`? `... WHERE auth_id IS NULL`?

Comment: @ChrisLear 1 row ever.  Just incrementing the value of auth_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
select ifnull(sequences.auth_id, x.auth_id) as auth_id from sequences right join (select 1 as auth_id) x on 1;
```

The assumption is that there's only 1 row in sequences. The trick is to make a right join to a fake table with only one row of its own, and then use the ifnull to get the wanted value.